# SQL Insert at 15 minute intervals, big MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly familiar with most aspects of web development and I consider myself a junior level programmer. I'm always anxious when I think about application scaling and would like to learn a little more about it. Let's have a hypothetical situation.

I'm working on a web application that polls a device and fetches about 2kb of XML data at 15 minute intervals. This data must be stored for A Very Long Time (at least a couple years?). Now imagine that this web application has 100 users that each have this device.

After 10 years we're talking tens of millions of table rows. With 100 users we have a cron job that is querying each users device, getting 2kb of XML, and inserting it into the SQL database every 15 minutes.

Assuming my queries are relatively simple, only collecting the columns necessary, using joins, and avoiding subqueries, is there any reason this should not scale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Assuming my queries are relatively simple, only collecting the columns
>   necessary, using joins, and avoiding subqueries, is there any reason
>   this should not scale?

When you get large you should put you active dataset in a in-memory database(faster than disc) just like Facebook, Twitter, etc do. Twitter became very slow when they did not put active dataset in memory/scale up => A lot of people called this fail whale. Both use [memcached](http://memcached.org/) for this, but you could also use [Redis](http://redis.io/)(I like this) or APC if you are just a single box. You should always install APC if want performance because APC is used  for caching the compiled bytecode.

> Most PHP accelerators work by caching the compiled bytecode of PHP
>   scripts to avoid the overhead of parsing and compiling source code on
>   each request (some or all of which may never even be executed). To
>   further improve performance, the cached code is stored in shared
>   memory and directly executed from there, minimizing the amount of slow
>   disk reads and memory copying at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, memcached is probably where I will end up eventually. The other answers were great too.

Comment: Your welcome. I also think you should have a look at Redis. It is nice. I forgot to mention this incredible good tutorial from Simon => http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

Inserting doesn't generally get slower as a table gets larger, but index updates may take longer. At some point you may want to split the table into two parts. One for archival storage, optimized for data retrieval (basically index the heck out of it), and a second table to handle the newer data, optimized more for insertion (fewer indexes).

But as always, the only way to tell for sure is to benchmark things. Set up some cloned tables with a few thousand rows, and some with multi-millions of rows, and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

You could always consider using [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-types.html) to automagically split your data files by date, and age older records off to an slower, high-capacity disk array while keeping the newer records (and the INSERTs) on a high-speed array. Then, your index builds will only have to work on a subset of the data rather than the whole deal, and should go quickly (disk I/O is typically the slowest part of a database system).